# Networking with 3 participants

Tags: networking

[image]
So, my problem is that I can't make the network above work.Sacrificing my laptop is kinda stupid (since I have two Zyxels at my disposal), so I would like someone to give me some tips on how to whip this little network into submission.
Can some of you write down how would you assign ip-s and Gateways in this particular case or if you are accustomed to this sort of problems tell me what should be done to liberate my laptop. Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry about it. The system is broken. There was a link that said it would generate a chat room and import the comments. That link failed to open a chat room. There was an error message along the lines of "Failed:..."  I will remove the comments  and i'm glad you have edited your question.  This is a fault with the system. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I have generated a chat link manually here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15106/discussion-between-gofun-and-barlop    this can be used to avoid elongated comments.

Comment: Sorry, I was stupid just ignore my last comment, thank you for the time you have spent helping me. I'll go try to apply what you have proposed. Thank you very much.

Comment: I just updated that chat link with some more info for you. Check back there and reply with how you get on.

Comment: I'm unable to chat due to my low reputation (at least 20 is required). I've been annoyingly polite because I felt that you really went out of your way in helping me. So, now when I spent, what in my opinion, seems to be more than enough weekends trying to mend this network, I now know that I'm not a miracle maker,I no longer want to go to the bottom of it. I'll just talk/pay/drink a sysadmin from my job into paying me a visit and hope he'll do all the miracle-working for me. Now, thank you very much for bearing with me and sorry for that I'm sort of abandoning my own campaign. Best of luck.

Comment: funnily enough you can just call the router manufacturer  and they'll just talk you through it. In fact, many computer technicians starting off will begin by calling the router manufacturer.  The other person you could call is your ISP.  The big ISPs like virgin deal with ignorant users non stop some of them are open 24 hours a day talking to ignorant computer users.

Comment: I guarantee you will one of the smarter people to call them! Most would lack the capacity to make the diagram you did or post on a forum. Call them and you might even learn what to do as they show you what to do